# Not able to insert records to custom pricebook through apex

Tags: apex

//( Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED, No standard price defined for this product: [])

global class SyncQuoteToOppLineItem{
    WebService static void callQuote(String oppID, String strQuoteID,String opLIId) {
          System.debug('**** ' + oppID + '      ' + opLIId + '      ' + strQuoteID );

```
         if(strQuoteID!=null){

            List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
             List<Product_Detail__c> lstPDet = new List<Product_Detail__c>();

                            List<Pricebook2> lstPRiceBook = [SELECT Id,IsActive,IsStandard,Name FROM Pricebook2 WHERE isActive = true AND IsStandard = false Limit 1];

            if(lstPRiceBook.size()>0){

                lstPDet = [SELECT AttachProduct__c,Name,Target_Rate__c,TotalCost__c,FlightStartDate__c,Adjusted_Rate__c,FlightEndDate__c,Game__c,Channel__c,OpportunityProducts__c,Target_Impression__c
                            FROM Product_Detail__c WHERE AttachProduct__c =:strQuoteID];

                for(Product_Detail__c obPD:lstPDet){
                    //Get the Product ID
                    System.debug('**** obPD.Name ' + obPD.Name);

                    List<PriceBookEntry> priceBookList = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Id, Product2.Name FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Product2.Name=:obPD.Name AND PriceBook2.id=:lstPRiceBook[0].id LIMIT 1];
                    if(priceBookList.size()>0){
                        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=oppID, PricebookEntryId=priceBookList[0].Id,Cost_Per_Impression__c=obPD.Adjusted_Rate__c,
                                             Game__c = obPD.Game__c, Platform__c=obPD.Channel__c);
                        oliList.add(oli);
                    }else{
                        //Inser the Prodcut and then add
                        Product2 p = new product2(name=obPD.Name,isActive=true);
                        insert p;

                        Id productId = p.id;

                         PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = lstPRiceBook[0].id, Product2Id = p.Id, UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true, UseStandardPrice = false);
                            insert pbe;
```

// Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED, No standard price defined for this product: []

```
                            OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=oppID, PricebookEntryId=pbe.Id,Cost_Per_Impression__c=obPD.Adjusted_Rate__c,
                                                 Game__c = obPD.Game__c, Platform__c=obPD.Channel__c);
                            oliList.add(oli);

                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've discovered how to fix this by now, but if not, I had this exact same error today and found the answer here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008yveIAA

In the future you should know that the wording of your question was not very good; you should have asked something like, "Cannot insert PriceBookEntry via APEX, Standard Price Not Defined" or "Cannot specify Standard Price of PriceBookEntry via APEX"

Use the wording of exceptions to help guide your search for answers.